# gapi calendar update deleted event 403

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I export my app events to Google calendar (`events.insert`). All of them are the recurrent events and have Google calendar ids composed in such a way to match my app events ids.

I also provide UI for deleting (`events.delete`) app-related (previously created) google events and have noticed that the events actually are never deleted, so I handle 409 error (The requested identifier already exists) to "restore" such events by `events.update` them.

And everything works fine - I can export/update/delete events as many times as I want either with my app or with Google calendar UI... **until** I've emptied calendar trash bin. After that, I still get 409 on attempt to insert event but the following `events.update` crashes with 403 code (`message: "Forbidden", reason: "forbidden"`).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you ever have any luck in fixing this? I'm trying to address the same problem.

Comment: @mattsl no, but I moved ids to `privateExtendedProperty`
`calendar.events.list({calendarId: 'primary', privateExtendedProperty: ['origin=gluuapp']})` and then `event.extendedProperties = {private: {origin: 'gluuapp',gluuId: event.gluuId}};calendar.events.insert({calendarId: 'primary', resource: event})`

Comment: @mattsl sorry, can't format message in comment, but you've got the idea - do not use google's ids but privateExtendedProperty

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't specifically need the ids to match, as I can just store them in the application's database. But, as you know, the undocumented behavior means I'll be writing a bunch of code that says "try to do do it this way and then assume this is why and try this".

If they insist on handling then events that way, they should at least return a specific error.